# JavaScript apply classList.toggle to only onclick element

Tags: javascript, dom, this

I have a function in my todo list app that generates my HTML:

```
function updateResults() {
            listItems = todos.reduce((result, item) => {
                result += `<li class="todo">${item}<div class="controls">
                <span class="check" onclick="checkItem()"></span><span class="delete">&#x1F5D1</span></div></li>`;
                return result;
            }, '');
            resultElement = document.getElementById('result');
            // Set inner HTML
            resultElement.innerHTML = listItems;
        }
```

When the 'check' span is clicked on one of the generated items, I want only that item to be checked, but I'm only able to toggle ALL list items at a time.

```
function checkItem() {
            [...document.getElementsByClassName('check')].forEach(function (item) {
                item.classList.toggle('checked');
            });
        }
```

I want to be using the 'this' keyword here right? I've tried a bunch of different syntax but have not been able to to target just the element that was clicked with my 'checked' class.

Thanks kindly.

Comment: Best suggestion is stop using inline `onclick` and use unobtrusive event listeners. You are using very modern ES6 spread operator in your code (circa 2016)  and 1990's event methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest removing the inline `onclick` (and your `checkItem` function) and creating an event listenter like this

```
// listen to all clicks on your page
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // if the clicked element has a class named check
  if (event.target.classList.contains('check')) {
    // remove or add the class checked only from this element
    event.target.classList.toggle('checked')
  }
})
```

This way only the clicked element with `check` class gets `checked` class applied.

You can read more about the `addEventListener` [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thank you, a working solution and cleaner way to write this.